# How can I generate a seed for np.random.uniform?

Tags: python, numpy, random-seed

I am trying to create 50 different cities with their latitudes and longitudes however each time I run I want the coordinates to be same.

```
lat = np.random.uniform(low=-90, high=90, size=50)
long = np.random.uniform(low=-180, high=180, size=50)
```

How can I provide a seed?

Comment: Googled for it: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html#numpy.random.seed

Comment: np.random.seed(seed)

Answer (score 3):

You can do as follow:

```
np.random.seed(42)
lat = np.random.uniform(low=-90, high=90, size=50)
long = np.random.uniform(low=-180, high=180, size=50)
```

Comment: adding https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/507/why-42-is-the-preferred-number-when-indicating-something-random for excessive completeness

Comment: number inside bracket of seed can be anything right?

Comment: Yes, it can be any 32 bit signed integer.